# NetLogo - Getting the 'who' of another turtle in the same patch

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking to get the 'who'/turtle ID of a turtle that occupies the same patch as another, and then add this as an item into a list for both turtles.

For example, say turtle A and turtle B are on the same patch, I'd like to store the who of turtle A in the list for turtle B and the who for turtle B in the list for turtle A.

I realise this may be quite a trivial thing to do, so I attempted to do this with the following code:

```
  if not any? turtles-on neighbors[
    if who != who[
      set collision-list fput (list (who)) collision-list
    ]
  ]
```

Here, I'm checking the patch to see if it contains another turtle, if it does then I'm trying to store the who (using a condition for if the who is not the same as the current who) and if it isn't, then store this in the collision-list for each agent.

Comment: Are you aware that you can put the turtles themselves in your lists?  Is there a reason not to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily it is a mistake to work with `who` numbers instead of the turtles themselves.  So I'll illustrate how you might augment a "collision list" of turtles.

```
turtles-own [clist]
to setup
  ca
  crt 100 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set clist []
  ]
  ask turtles [adjust-clist]
end

to adjust-clist ;turtle proc
  let _ts [self] of (other turtles-here)
  set clist (sentence _ts clist)
end
```